# Download file into a var

Tags: csv, authentication, download

Good morning

I am searching for a solution to put a file , thats gets downloaded from a webpage , into a variable. But what every i do i can not get the file to to a variable. This because it is not a direct download. There is a widget between me and the file.

I can get the file to download , to my PC , when ever i create a page with the following code.

```
<?php
        print "<form id='page-signinForm' action='https://www.zazzle.com/lgn/signin' accept-charset='UTF-8' method='post' novalidate='novalidate' target='hidden-form'>";
        print " <input type='hidden' name='process' id='process' value='login'>";
        print " <input type='hidden' name='lru' id='lru' value='http://www.zazzle.com/'>";
        print " <input type='hidden' name='tosmsg' id='tosmsg' value='True'>";
        print " <input id='page_username-input' name='login_username' type='hidden' placeholder='' class='error' value='userID'>";
        print " <input id='page_password-input' name='login_password' type='hidden' placeholder='' value='Password'>";
        print " <input  type='submit' value='Sign in' >";
        print "</form>";

        print "<IFRAME style='display:none' name='hidden-form'></IFRAME> ";

        print "<iframe src="http://www.zazzle.com/my/earnings/royaltyhistory?exportCsv=1"></iframe>:'
?>
```

You will be unable to test this if you do not have a zazzle account. 
Is there a good way to do this.

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but if you are looking for ways to 'download a remote file (at somewhere on the Internet) and save its content into a variable', I'd suggest you look into [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) of PHP.

If the file is not directly accessible by either, you could first download and save the file to a location with the 'widget' you mentioned and then use file_get_content of PHP to get the content into a variable.

Comment: The problem is how to redirect de widget to download it to the server and not to my browser.

Comment: OK it looks hard to me to fully automate this without somehow cracking the widget. Sorry I can't help :-(

Comment: So there is no way that in the session i can redirect where something goes.

Comment: If you can find out how the widget is getting the content you need, say which url it uses to download, then it's easy enough to write another widget to download the file to your server. But the deal breaker is you have to sign in to download. As far as I know it's very complex to let a php script sign in as yourself and download. So my conclusion would be, as long as the user authentication is there in the way, you can only download manually on your browser. Then upload to the server.